# How to get cellid and pci in 5g SA

Tags: android, telephonymanager, cellid, 5g

I am developing an app in which i need some network parameters cell id and pci.I have 5g enable device with android 10. I am trying to access cell id through telephonic manager here is code.

`List<CellInfo> allCellInfo = telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo();`

`for (CellInfo info : allCellInfo){ if (info instanceof CellInfoNr && info.isRegistered()){ }}`

But allCellInfo getting null.I am talking about 5g SA (Qualcomm device).

I have seen this post [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59299371/measuring-5gnew-radio-data) but not really helps. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So search a lot but didnt find any relevant answer finally i update my Android 10 5g device to Android 11 5g device and it works for me with the same function.